# Spotify API: get random songs

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

Hello people on stackoverflow,

I have to make a webapp with spotify for my study. I decided to make an application where you get a 30 seconds preview of a random song. You are able to like or dislike the song.

So what do i have to do to get random songs out of spotify. Can anyone help me please. it would help me a lot!

Thanks for your help!!

Regards

---

EDIT

I'm trying to use the Spotify API to create an application that finds and plays a random song from the Spotify library.

In the Spotify API you can get one single track. To get the track, you need a TrackId. You can get all songs from user's library, but instead of getting just the tracks from the user's library, I want tracks from the whole spotify library. In the Spotify API Developers area there isn't something about getting all tracks from the spotify library.

I can load an album and get one track out of that album. And do that every single time, but that isn't easy at all. So I would like to know if there is an easier solution to get all tracks from spotify.

Comment: You haven't really specified anything except some very high level requirements, which will probably cause your question to be downvoted because it's too broad.

- What have you tried so far?
- What technologies are you comfortable with, or what are you aiming to use?
- What issues do you foresee having?

Comment: @michaelt You're completely right. First thing i posted here, so i was too general in my explanation..:$ I updated it a bit. I hope it's better now. I hope you can help me. I saw you're from Spotify so maybe you know more about it.

Answer (score 2):

I got this as a solution. I think this is the best solution to get random tracks out of Spotify. Let me know what you guys think of this. It isn't completely random, but it's a kind of.:)

```
//make a variable with some search queries and put it in an array. (you can create more search queries.
$getRandomSongsArray = array('%25a%25', 'a%25', '%25e%25', 'e%25', '%25i%25', 'i%25', '%25o%25', 'o%25');

//This will get a random result out of the array above
$getRandomSongs = $getRandomSongsArray[array_rand($getRandomSongsArray)];

//This will get a random offset number between 1 and 1000. So you get a random track. (you can change the numbers btw)
$getRandomOffset = rand(1, 1000);

//This is the url that gets the results out of the Spotify API. You have to put in the variables you created above.
$url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=$getRandomSongs&offset=$getRandomOffset&limit=1&type=track&market=NL";
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created some Python code to get random songs from the Spotify Web API based on OP solution but giving the posibility to look for a specific genre. I've also scrapped [Everynoise](http://everynoise.com) to get a list of every valid genre handled by the API since I couldn't find any list on the documentation and it seems to work fine.

All the code is available on: https://github.com/ZipBomb/spotify-song-suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random ID (it looks to be a 22 character base 62 string) and check, somehow, if it's a valid track? Probably arduous but simple, if you can check a song exists.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try that. I'll let you know if it works or not. It would be a simple solution and it's possible I think.:) @Liam

Comment: I hope you are not serious with your proposal. That's like telling somebody to generate a number with 32 random bits and then check if it's between 0 and 100 to find a proper random number.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get all tracks or a track from the entire Spotify catalogue using the Spotify Web API. Instead of scraping the API, I'd recommend that you enable your users to at least select a genre or a search word and retrieve tracks based on that using the [Search endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/).